# SelectizeJS Using ul li instead of select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, selectize.js, typehead

im wondering how to use dropdown tag suggestion but with ul li instead of 
`<select><option>TEXT</option></select>`
because i wanna style use heading title and description. and its possible to use html tag inside option select.

here's the example of my code

```
                <select id="select-state" name="diagnosa" multiple class="demo-default">
                    <option value="Kolesterol">Kolesterol</option>
                    <option value="Diabetes">Diabetes</option>
                    <option value="Kesemutan">Kesemutan</option>
                    <option value="Sakit Perut">Sakit Perut</option>
                    <option value="Sakit Gigi">Sakit Gigi</option>
                    <option value="Cek Gula">Cek Gula</option>
                    <option value="Gula Darah">Gula Darah</option>
                </select>
```

its impossible to use

```
<option value="Gula Darah">
<h2>Gula Darah</h2>
<p class="desc">the desciption</p>
</option>
```

i need help guys, its possible to change it to ul li using selectizejs? or you can recommend me another plugin.

thanks